# Explode Content within specific HTML element

Tags: php, content

I am trying to insert some ad code in a site after X number of elements. The base code I am using was from using

tags (from:  http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-insert-ads-within-your-post-content-in-wordpress/):

```
function prefix_insert_after_list_item( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
  $closing_p = '</p>';
  $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
  var_dump($paragraphs);
  foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

    if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
      $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
    }

    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
      $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
    }
  }

  return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Instead of paragraphs, I am trying to insert them between certain  elements. Here is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="listing">
  <div class="list-item">
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to insert the ads between the list items. Replacing `$closing_p = '</p>';` with `$closing_p = '<div class="list-item">';` doesn't seem to work though. Is there a way with to target the overall $content element in WordPress, but then target 's within the parent 'listing' ? Or is there another/better way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it to work by changing it to this:

```
$closing_p = '</div>';
```

I hope I didn't miss something

Comment: The issue is </div> isn't selective enough. There are additional divs in the $content element that I don't want to be selecting. I went ahead and implemented via JS. I decided that was a safer option than trying to manipulate the DOM via PHP like I was trying to do.